# Question mark in SWI-Prolog - nondeterministic functor

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I've just tried to implement absolute function in Prolog and I've got some strange behavior. My code was:

```
absval(X, RESULT) :- X >= 0, RESULT is X.
absval(X, RESULT) :- X < 0, RESULT is -X.
```

And when I try in SWI-Prolog `absval(-2,X).` I get

```
X = 2

yes
```

as expected. But otherwise when I invoke `absval(2,X)`, I get `X = 2 ?` and I should insert another input. After pressing enter I get also `yes`.

What does mean the second one result? What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: The behavior you encounter can be explained by the fact that your program is not deterministic. There are two rules for `absval/2`. So, after Prolog satisfies `absval(2,X)` using the first rule, it backtracks in order to resatisfy the goal. The first subgoal `(X < 0)` of the second rule will fail and you will not get a second solution. In order to have a deterministic behavior, add a cut operator after `X>=0` like this: `absval(X, RESULT) :- X >= 0, !, RESULT is X.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you report doesn't match the behaviour I get here:

```
?- absval(2,X).
X = 2 ;
false.
```

that's actually what is expected.

If you need to make it deterministic, use a cut, or better, the 'if/then/else' construct:

```
absval(X, RESULT) :- X >= 0 -> RESULT is X ; RESULT is -X.
```

Comment: ok, I see. and additional question: is there any way to express this without using neither if/then/else nor cuts?

Comment: AFAIK, no. Your code it's already correct, the non determinism is unavoidable without cut...

Comment: No, no, no! You have to see the signs! :-)

Answer (score 1):

A deterministic version using a single clause without cuts of if-then-else constructs:

```
absolute_value(Value, AbsoluteValue) :-
    AbsoluteValue is sign(Value) * Value.
```

Note that `sign/1` is a standard built-in arithmetic function.

Comment: `abs` also. I try to express if/else construction from procedural language using multiple functors.